# How to get value of ng-change ionic/angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I m new in angularJS:

When I change the value of my input, in my console I don t have the new value.
 How can I get the new value of my input when I change it?

**controller.js:**

```
$scope.nam = guillaume;
$scope.firstchange = function(){
    $scope.displayed = {'display':'block'};
    console.log($scope.nam);

};
```

**home.html:**

```
<input ng-change="firstchange()" ng-model="nam" class="param-right"></input><p>Prénom</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the model as a parameter to your handler.

**controller.js**

```
$scope.nam = guillaume;
$scope.firstchange = function(nam){
    $scope.displayed = {'display':'block'};
    console.log(nam);

};
```

**home.html**

```
<input ng-change="firstchange(nam)" ng-model="nam" class="param-right"></input><p>Prénom</p>
```

Comment: @AndreFeijo Please, consider adding some explanations... "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)